# VM4242:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier 'Object' setTimeout (async) (anonymous) @ (index):137 (anonymous) @ (index):139

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, syntax-error

When i upgrade ruby 2.7.1 to 3.2.2 and rails 6 to 7 it gives me a lot of error one of them is this VM4242:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier 'Object'
setTimeout (async)

How would we solve this error.

Comment: That looks more like a JavaScript error